# ¿Cómo configurar correctamente los estilos de la barra de tareas?

Tags: android

Quiero saber cómo debo configurar correctamente los estilos del toolbar pues en `styles.xml` tengo lo sigueinte:

```
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

y el `tool_bar.xml` esto:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:elevation="4dp"
android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"

android:id="@+id/tool_bar">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

y el resultado que me arroja la APP es así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero lograr es que el item igual se muestre blanco, como una app normal.

Comment: David, revisa lo que comento en mi respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo estas configurando correctamente pero para mostrar los colores que deseas, tienes que revisar en tu archivo `colors.xml` que colores tienes definidos para `colorPrimary`.

Supongo que esta definido actualmente como:

```
 <color name="colorPrimary">@color/blue</color>
```

debes cambiar a color blanco.

Comment: Hola, lo cambié a color blanco y la toolbar aparecía en todo color blanco, y el ítem "powered by techfull" igual de color de fondo gris oscuro :/